# Hibernate keeps adding unwanted UK constraints

Tags: sql-server, hibernate

my hibernate/sqlserver fellow frameworks have a strange behavior : they keep adding UK constraints I don't want... and I don't undestand where thoses constraints come from (I don't create them!).

Here's the table that get an extra UK randomly :

```
CREATE TABLE TableA_TableB
(
  TableA_id          numeric(19,0)   NOT NULL,                                 
  TableB_id          NUMERIC(19,0)   NOT NULL 
);

ALTER TABLE TableA_TableB ADD CONSTRAINT TableA_FK FOREIGN KEY (TableA_id)     REFERENCES TableA(id);
ALTER TABLE TableA_TableB ADD CONSTRAINT TableB_FK FOREIGN KEY (TableB_id) REFERENCES TableB(id);
CREATE INDEX TableA_TableB_IDX ON TableA_TableB (TableA_id,TableB_id);
```

The result of it is ok. I insert a few data in Table A and B, and suddenly, some of this appears : ***UK_weirgodduk***

```
SELECT
   OBJECT_NAME(o.parent_object_id)
   FROM
      sys.objects o
   WHERE
      o.name = 'UK_weirgodduk' AND o.parent_object_id <> 0
```

=>

```
  'TableA_TableB'
```

I don't have any idea where this comes from... (hibernate? SqlServer?)
But I suppose there's stg I didn't undestand about link tables or/and hibernate... any tip or idea?

Thank you for reading until here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I enventually found the responsible for this problem :
@OneToMany instead of @ManyToMany, with the thankfull help of the sessionFactory's '*hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto*' set to '*update*'.

I think it's one more point for NOT using The later one!